# Mouse cursor coordinates over image: <br/> not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks to the suggestions I received [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235664/overlay-showing-mouse-cursor-coordinates-relative-to-an-image-when-mouse-cursor), I cleaned up my code and I'm now using pure jQuery. I made slight edits to a script I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414984/how-could-i-display-x-y-coordinates-on-image-in-real-time-to-the-user-when-the) and I've got this:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip">' ).appendTo( 'body' )[0];

$( 'img' ).
    each(function () {
        var pos = $( this ).position(),
            top = pos.top,
            left = pos.left,
            width = $( this ).width(),
            height = $( this ).height(); 
        $( this ).
            mousemove(function ( e ) {
                var x = e.pageX - left,
                    y = e.pageY - top;

                $( tooltip ).text( 'x = ' + x + ', y = ' + y ).css({
                    left: e.clientX + 10,
                    top: e.clientY + 10
                }).show();
            }).
            mouseleave(function () {
                $( tooltip ).hide();
            }); 

    });

};
```

I have a problem: I tried changing one line of my code to:

```
$( tooltip ).text( 'x = ' + x + '<br/> y = ' + y ).css({
```

but it does not work. Instead of breaking the line, I get this:

[image: line break not working]

Comment: If you want to add HTML to your tooltip, you need to use `.html()`, not `.text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
$( tooltip ).text( 'x = ' + x + '<br/> y = ' + y ).css({
```

to:

```
$( tooltip ).html( 'x = ' + x + '<br/> y = ' + y ).css({
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Roev! I'll accept your answer and edit the question so that there is only one question, then I'll open another question.

Comment: Done. Now my question only contains one topic.